# AngularJS Firebase database query filter based on other database

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-ng-repeat, firebase-realtime-database

I get the values stored in the "projects" field under a current user's data in Firebase database called **users**:

**first method:**

```
var promise = MyUser.user();
promise.then( function onSuccess(user) {
    $scope.userprojectskeys  = user.projects;
});
```

**second method:**

```
var keyquery = DatabaseRef.ref('/users/' + userId).orderByKey().once("value")
    .then(function onSuccess(snapshot) {
        snapshot.child("savedprojects").forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var userprojects = childSnapshot.val();
            console.log("my list is :", userprojects );
        });
    });
```

the `$scope.userprojectskeys` of the first method and the `userprojects` of the second method both return the data needed:
**first method output:**
[image]

**second method output:**

```
my list is : -KUTLAZENGlxtzCtEfaZ
my list is : -KUTLM8r_kmVSTaxzLW5
my list is : -KUTPrs6ARZXjbjtNr7O
```

On the other hand, I have another function which gets the list of children under another database called **projects** like the following:

```
var projectquery = DatabaseRef.ref("projects").orderByKey().equalTo("-KUTPrs6ARZXjbjtNr7O");
$scope.projectslist = $firebaseArray(projectquery);
```

what I am doing now is ng-repeating the fields of the object in `$scope.projectslist`, displaying the fields for each project.

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in projectslist">
    <td>{{ obj.field1}}</td>
    <td>{{ obj.field2 }}</td>
    <td>{{ obj.field3 }}</td>
    <td>{{ obj.field4 }}</td>
</tr>
```

### Question :

how is it possible to pass the above list of project keys obtained previously from current user's data (either using first or second method) into the latter function which shows the projects and filters them by key in `equalTo()`?

but as you can see, I am passing one project ID manually to my filter `equalTo`, and it is working. But I need to pass in all of the keys into equalTo.

### one proposed method is:

one proposed method is to combine these two functions like this:

```
$scope.projectslist = [];
DatabaseRef.ref('/users/' + userId).orderByKey().once("value")
    .then(function onSuccess(snapshot) {
        snapshot.child("projects").forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
            var userprojects = childSnapshot.val();
            var projectquery = DatabaseRef.ref("projects").orderByKey().equalTo(userprojects);
            $scope.projectslist.push($firebaseArray(projectquery));
        });
    });
```

but this is with no success! the table is showing the rows, but no value inside: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EaPu.jpg 
here is the screenshot of the debugger: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C9zr.png

### update:

here is the structure of my `users` child in **mydatabase** in firebase:
[image]

 In which you can see five users, and for each user, there are a number of fields, one of which is a field that stores the user projects keys and in this example, the user has four project keys.

and here is the projects child in firebase **mydatabase**:
[image]

 here we see the global view of my firebase databse.
So the goal is to look up the projects keys from **users** and then show the corresponding projects from the projects database, that is ng-repeat the fields of those projects.

### update:

here is the console log after Zura's suggestion:

```
$scope.projectslist = [];
DatabaseRef.ref('/users/' + userId).orderByKey().once("value")
    .then(function onSuccess(snapshot) {
        snapshot.child("projects").forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
            var userprojects = childSnapshot.val();
            //console.log("loaded. Data: ", userprojects);
            var projectquery = DatabaseRef.ref("projects").orderByKey().equalTo(userprojects);

            var list = ($firebaseArray(projectquery));
            console.log("list: ", list);

        });
    });
```

each list contains the info I need for each project of the current user. Perfect!
But how to access them and store them in a `$scope`to be able to call it in my html?

[image]

### update:

I can only show the last project by passing the list into a **$scope**:
The project shown is the last of the **forEach** iteration. **The question is how can I show all of the iterations of forEach and pass it into an array?**

### update 25.10.2016:

here is an updated version of the code which concatenates the objects: first one, then the first two together, the first three, and at last all objects concatenated into one big array, see the console log below:

```
 $scope.projectslist = [];

DatabaseRef.ref('/users/' + userId).orderByKey().once("value")
    .then(function onSuccess(snapshot) {
        snapshot.child("projects").forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
            var userprojects = childSnapshot.val();
            var projectquery = DatabaseRef.ref("projects").orderByKey().equalTo(userprojects);

            var list = $firebaseArray(projectquery);

            $scope.list = $firebaseArray(projectquery);
            console.log("list: ", $scope.list);
            list.$loaded(function(){
                 $scope.projectslist = $scope.projectslist.concat(list);
                 console.log("loaded: ", $scope.projectslist);
            });

        });
    });
```

[image]

 and each object directly contains the info I need as shown in the previous object screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Recommendations

- When it is possible always use [angularfire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire) vs original firebase
  promises. [AngularFire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire) does 3 way binding + `$scope.$apply`
  automatically. So you do not have to think about it.
- Use `$firebaseObject` instead of `$firebaseArray` if you are fetching
  only one object.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Your problem is in the following code.

```
$scope.projectslist.push($firebaseArray(projectquery));
```

`firebaseArray()` returns array and what `push` method do is that it pushes given parameter at the end of the array. So here, you will have array which contains also arrays. 
Instead you want to concat existing array with `$firebaseArray(projectquery)`.

I suggest to try the following code.

```
var projectquery = DatabaseRef.ref("projects").orderByKey().equalTo(userprojects);
var list = $firebaseArray(projectquery);
list.$loaded(function(){
    $scope.projectslist.contact(list);
});
```

And if you are using [angularfire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire) I think you should modify fetching user's projects also using `$firebaseObject`. And you do not need to use `orderByKey` because you are fetching only one object.

```
var user = $firebaseObject(DatabaseRef.ref('/users/' + userId));
user.$loaded(function(){
    console.log("User loaded. Data: ", user);
    angular.forEach(user.projects, function(value, key){
        var projectquery = DatabaseRef.ref("projects").orderByKey().equalTo(key);
        // var list = $firebaseArray(projectquery);
        // list.$loaded(function(){
        //    $scope.projectslist = $scope.projectslist.concat(list);
        // });
        // or shortly. Replace 4 lines above with this line.
        $scope.projectslist.push($firebaseObject(projectquery));
    });
});
```

#### UPDATE

As you are getting only one list it would be better to try `$firebaseObject` and get object and push it in array.

#### UPDATE 25.10.2016:

Now your problem is here.

```
DatabaseRef.ref('/users/' + userId).orderByKey().once("value")
    .then(function onSuccess(snapshot) {
        snapshot.child("projects").forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
```

This is not done according my suggestion. You are NOT using angularfire and html is NOT automatically recompiled. You should call `$scope.$apply` at the end of `onSuccess` promise or better... You should use angularfire approach - `$firebaseObject` which automatically calls `$scope.$apply`.

```
var user = $firebaseObject(DatabaseRef.ref('/users/' + userId));
user.$loaded(function(){
    console.log("User loaded. Data: ", user);
    angular.forEach(user.projects, function(value, key){
```

Comment: My first question is what is **contact** in your last line appended to list? where did it come from? what does it do? I don't have it in the original code in the question. 
Second, I tried to implement your answer, but no success. And when I implement your second code, I get warning on duplicate declaration for **user** . Could you please revisit your answer and let me know if you have any suggestions?

Comment: I added the requested screenshots of my database structure.

Comment: do you mean **concat** by **contact**, to concatenate? anyway I tried this as well, but no success.

Comment: I replaced `$scope.projectslist.push($firebaseArray(projectquery));`with your suggestion: `var list = $firebaseArray(projectquery);` the **list** contains what I need! but they are stored at [0] of each array. How to concatenate them? here is my console log for **list** added to the question..

Comment: Yes it should be concat instead of contact. Sorry for this typo mistake. And after concatenation it returns new array instead of modifying existing. Check my updated answer.

Comment: thanks. I don't understand which four lines I should replace? Could you edit your answer write down the definitive suggestion? anyway i tried it but not working. i might be missing some point.

Comment: I have updated answer. Can you check and let me know. It should work.

Comment: it returns absolutely nothing! However, I am going to update my question with an edit + screenshot inspired by your code, which concatenates the objects one after another, but I still have problem calling them correctly to be able to access them in my html view.

Comment: Can you share the whole code which you have now? I think yiu are missing something

Comment: I have shared the whole code now, that generated the console log that I also shared in the very last update.

Comment: I strictly get nothing after your last edit: here is my code http://pastebin.com/yJEgT4g1
and nothing in the console log.

Comment: Sorry I had mistake in `angular.forEach` line. I have updated the code. Try now.

Comment: here is my complete view controller code, you can find the related code to the question right at the bottom of the code. http://pastebin.com/9pyWbWe7

Comment: here is the entire code after your forEach update: http://pastebin.com/dwuf3NXM
still absolutely nothing in view nor in console log.